# tail -f does not follow files on WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, tail

I have :

```
F:\xampp-htdocs>wsl --list
Windows Subsystem für Linux-Distributionen:
Ubuntu-22.04 (Standard)
```

I cd into my logfiles on Window 11:

```
/mnt/d/xampp-2024-15-01/apache/logs$
```

there i do

```
tail -f access.log
```

Tail just outputs the last lines but then does no longer follow the file.
Tried this with different files within WSL and Windows11. no luck,

On an remote, external real Ubuntu "20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)" system, `tail -f` works as expected.

What am i missing ?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69331285/10765659

Comment: Thanks Kamil but the sugestions there do not work

Answer (score 1):

The core issue is that the `inotify` API is not supported by the Plan 9 (9P) network filesystem used by WSL2 for access to Windows drives.  This impacts things like `tail` as well as "hot reload" features in many development tools (e.g., `npm watch`).

This occurs in WSL2 when:

- A Linux app is attempting to use `inotify` to watch for filesystem changes (in this case, of course, `tail -f`)
- The file is located on a Windows drive (as you said, `/mnt/d`)
- (I'm fairly sure) A Windows process is writing to the file.  When growing the file with a Linux process in WSL2 (e.g. `echo foo >> file_name`) results in a successful update of `tail -f` for me.

Normal workarounds:

- If possible, store your file on the Linux filesystem.  Sometimes this is possible, other times it's not.
- Use polling in place of `inotify` if the app supports it.  In this case, as in one of the [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70259631/11810933) that @KamilMaciorowski pointed you to in the comments, that's done with `tail -f ---disable-inotify <file>`, but you replied that none of the answers worked for you.

  This *could* be due to a different version of `tail` than that answer used.  You could also try adding a retry interval:

  ```
  tail -f ---disable-inotify -s 1 <filename>
  ```
- A "traditional" suggestion in the past has been to use WSL1 if it works for your use case. However, with WSL1 having not received an update in a few years now, it's becoming harder to justify its use.  Still, it remains an option.  Under WSL1, `inotify` works on Windows drives.
- For `tail` specifically, you can do a bit of a hacky workaround:

  ```
  pwsh.exe -c 'Get-Content <windows_path_to_file> -wait'
  ```

  Notes:

  - If you don't have PowerShell Core installed, either (recommended) install it or, alternatively, use `powershell.exe`.
  - As noted, since you are using PowerShell from inside WSL, you'll be using the *Windows* path to the file. E.g., `D:\xampp-2024-15-01\apache\logs$`.
  - Quoting/escaping can be a challenge when nesting shells.
  - Credit to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15556018/11810933) for the `-Wait`.
  - You can, of course, alias or wrap this in a shell function or script.